# Same div id on current and the page loaded by ajax request can create issue?

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook

I am working with facebook programming which needs to  keep 
`<div id="fb-root" ></div>`.

On my first page I perform facebook login via button click which needs above div to be kept. This has no issue.

Now when user click on the button on index.php, through ajax new page `url.php` is loaded into `<div>` on `index.php` page. 
This `url.php` page contains code for facebook comment box. Which again uses `<div id="fb-root" ></div>.`
So having this same div id on both `index.php` and `url.php` can create problem?

When I load `url.php` diretly the `facebook comment box` appears correctly, but when first I load `index.php` and through ajax request `url.php` is called comment box does not appear.

Here is code for facebook comment box on url.php :

```
   <div id="fb-root" ></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=9549";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-comments" data-colorscheme="light" data-width="470" style="z-index: 1; left: 420px; top: 560px; "  ></div>
```

While index.php

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
    appId: '<?php
echo $appId;
?>',
    cookie: true,
    xfbml: true,
//  channelUrl: '<?php
echo $return_url;
?>channel.php',
    oauth: true});}; .....
```

**UPDATE**

Code which perform ajax call:

```
 if (response.status === "connected")
        {
            LodingAnimate(); 
            FB.api('/me?fields=movies,email', function(mydata) {
            console.log(mydata.email);

            //alert("json-5");
            var json = JSON.stringify(mydata.movies.data);
        //    alert(mydata.movies);
            var a = JSON.parse(json);       
            $.post('movies_db.php',{'myd':a}, function(data) 
            {
                $.ajax({
            url:'url.php'
            ,async:     true
            ,cache:     false
            ,dataType:  'html'
            ,success:   function(data){
                $('body').html(data);
                    }
        });        
            });
        console.log(data);

              }); //--
         } //if
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is remove the `<div id="fb-root" ></div>` from the `url.php` page you use to load the comment box. Instead, use the JavaScript function `FB.XFBML.parse();` in your ajax `success` or `callback` method to render the comment box using the existing div.

jQuery Example:

```
$.post( 'url.php', data, function( response ) {
    $('.comment-box').html( response );
    FB.XFBML.parse();
}, 'html' );
```

The `FB.XFBML.parse();` function will render the comment box and any other Facebook elements you have on the page.

Comment: I have added the code where ajax call performed. Where should I place the code you did?

Comment: comment-box is the class for the div you want to place the Facebook Comment Plugin in. You can change that line accordingly to use a ID or different class.
From you code, you just need to use `FB.XFBML.parse()` at the end of your Ajax code to display the comment plugin.